# Anyway to load an external script once on an event in an all ajax web page?

Tags: ajax, jquery, lazy-loading

The page i have is very simple, but all of the links are loaded with ajax, what i am wondering is there anyway to load an external script once one of the links is clicked, but make sure that the script is only loaded once? Basically just for the sake of performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load an external script by creating a `script` element and appending it to `head`:

```
var script=$("<script>");
script.attr("type", "text/javascript");
script.attr("src", "some_external_script.js");
script.appendTo("head");
```

You can use a simple variable to make sure it's only included once.

```
var addedExternalScript=false;
// ...somewhere else where loadedExternalScript is still in scope...
if(!addedExternalScript) {
    // load the script
}
// script is in the document
```

Note that having the script element in the document won't necessarily mean it's loaded. You may need to bind to the `load` event if you want to know when the script has loaded.

Comment: ah, yeah i was wondering if there was a way to do so without just setting a global variable, but it's probably my best and the easiest option.

Answer (score 1):

Is this code helpful to you?

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.async = true;
        s.src = 'script.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this code before, and it worked:

```
var t=document;
var o=t.createElement('script');
o=t.standardCreateElement('script');
o.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
o.setAttribute('src','http://www.example.com/js/jquery-1.3.2.js');
t.lastChild.firstChild.appendChild(o);
```